# Calculate a square diagonal based on 2 constraints

Tags: geometry

I have a rectangle of a unequal width (W) and height (H) in which I want to place a number of squares that would fit both the width and the height. The image below shows that the diagonal of the square would not fit within the height.

Is there a way to determine the square's diagonal based on the rectangles' width and height?

Update: imagine there's no white space/limiter between the squares.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the squares are the biggest possible that fit (no "wasted edges), then the sides of the squares are the Greatest Common Divisor of the edges (given that they are integers, or could be represented as integers) This is because the squares sides have to be able to divide into each side length, and this gives the biggest ones that do that.

The diagonals of these squares are just $\sqrt{2}$ times the edges of the squares, just by Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Thanks John! I tried your solution (i.e. sqrt(2*width*height) but it returns a value higher than the width or height itself. For instance, with a width of 768 and a height of 788, the result is 1100

Comment: the gcd of 768 and 788 is 4. The squares, that fill it completely, and are as big as possible, have a side length of 4, and a diagonal of $4\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @user029450 edges of the squares, not the rectangle. The squares sides are found with the greatest common divisor of the sides.

Comment: ah, thanks for the clarification! But, in that case if I want a greater square I can use 4 as base and vary the exponent until I get a preferred sized square.

Comment: 4 is the biggest square you can use with integer sides, with 192 squares by 197 squares. Any bigger side length will make it so there are either empty areas or parts of squares left over